# Grails: Use year in domain

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-domain-class

I'm trying to create a domain class with a year column. My project connects to a MySQL database. After a little research, I find the year(4) is the ideal type which could be used in MySQL.
So I set up the domain class like:

```
class FiscalYear {
    Date labelYear // This should be a year
}
```

And when migrating data, I modified the changelog.groovy a little bit - I changed the date to year(4):

```
databaseChangeLog = {

    changeSet(author: "me", id: "1435253213953-1") {
        createTable(tableName: "fiscal_year") {
            ...
            column(name: "label_year", type: "year(4)") {
                constraints(nullable: "false")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is not working. I got a **Data truncated for column 'label_year'**  exception when I was saving a new instance of the domain:

```
new FiscalYear(labelYear:Date.parse('yyyy', '2015')).save()
```

Could anyone tell me that how to correctly map a domain attribute to a year(4) type in MySQL?

Comment: Maybe possible by some custom mapping, but I would advise you to just use a MySQL date or int and be done with it. You probably won't notice the difference and can save your efforts for other challenges.

Comment: @wwwclaes Thank you! I think your comment is practical. I will try Short as year.